# Accessing XPATH for multivalued field in schema

Tags: experience-manager

I have a schema which has a field (lets take title)  as a multi valued. and I am getting only one XPATH for all the title values.  Is there a way to excess all the values because as I have only 1 XPATH , I am unable to edit the field through XPM.
Has someone encounter that problem ?

Title -ABC,
       DEF,
       GHI 
    But for all three titles I am getting just one XPATH.

Thanks

Comment: Is this in template code?

Comment: Can you please add code snippet on how you are accessing xpath?

Comment: Hi Dhruva. Welcome to tridion.stackexchange. I'm fairly sure someone here can help you, but we'll need the question to be clearer. Please could you update it to show exactly what you've tried so far, what results you expected and what you got instead?

Answer (score 3):

You likely need to use position, as the XML will use the same name for all instances of field X

So assuming your content is like:

```
<Content>
   <title>Title 1</title>
   <title>Title 2</title>
   <title>Title 3</title>
</Content>
```

In XPath you would address them

```
//title[1]
//title[2]
//title[3]
```

**note** - xpath uses a 1 based, not zero based array

Comment: It is very standard xpath, nothing to-do with SDL :) I've removed word SDL